# eregi include extra characters into the allowed list

Tags: php, whitespace

```
/* Check if username is not valid */
     else if(!eregi("/[^a-z0-9\s\' ']/i", $subuser)){
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not valid");
     }
```

How to I allow for spaces to be allowed in the eregi line??

On a sidenote...
I was going to use:

```
$input_name = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $input_name)
```

to strip excess white space, can this be done in a one liner using eregi?

Comment: how do you propose doing validation and replacement as a single action?

Comment: Use trim() to strip the whitespace. No need to use a regular expression when a native function does the job.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible, but i thought i would ask just in case

Comment: TMK, not specific to PHP5. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PHP5, you should drop ereg functions altogether. They've already been deprecated in 5.3.

```
if (!preg_match('/[\w\s]+/',$subuser)
   echo 'Invalid';
```

Comment: Thank you, problem solved!   Also, thanks for the heads up on ereg!